# Как запустить код из строки javascript, как полноценный скрипт?

Tags: javascript, eval, code-injection

Мне нужно запустить javascript код из строки, как полноценный скрипт. Я пробовал сделать это с помощью вызова функции `eval`, однако в таком случае, например, есть проблемы с объявлением классов

```js
let code = "class A { test() {console.log('A class');} }; new A().test();";
eval(code);
new A().test();
```

В этом примере будет успешно создан экземпляр класса A в коде, записанном в строке, однако попытка создать экземпляр данного объявленного класса ниже выбросит исключение

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined
```

Мне же нужно, чтобы, например, работало что-то наподобие кода ниже:

```
// Do something
executeScript(getScriptFromUrl("scipr url here"));
let obj = new ClassFromScript();
obj.doSomething();
```

Есть ли в javascript какой-то инструмент для выполнения скриптов прямо из строки?
Интересна реализация конкретно на **клиентской стороне** (т.е., добавить нужный код на сервере и отдать на клиент не подойдёт)

Comment: ты просто синтаксис языка не знаешь, для начала надо изучить его........т.к. проблема заключалась как минимум в том, что надо скобки ставить `(new A()).test()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, `new` вообще не нужно, там конструктора нет, к тому же через прототип нужно обращаться. `A.prototype.test()`

Comment: @ΝNL993    %))))))

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский, во-первых, читайте внимательнее, я написал, в строке аналогичный участок кода без проблем выполнился. Во-вторых, тут всё в порядке с синтаксисом, перепроверил ещё раз. В-третьих, выброшенное исключение явно показывает на то, что проблема не в синтаксисе.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1IQU.png

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понимаю... (P. S. FF лучше)

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский читайте внимательнее. Нет проблемы с интерпретацией кода из строки. Есть проблема с созданием экземпляра, объеявленного в строке, класса ниже

Comment: Попробуйте варианты [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298985/using-eval-method-to-get-class-from-string-in-firefox)

Comment: @NikitaAndreev  ну зависит от того, что ты вообще хочешь делать и что творить....и в чём вообще смысла всего этого....... так-то код `var code = "(class A { test() {console.log('A class');} })";
var yo = eval(code);
(new yo).test()`  вполне себе сработает.......... а вот если ты, условно, хочешь внедрить произвольный код и с ним работать, как будто он есть на странице - то это немного изврат и попахивает попыткой хакинга))